# Gain Muscle Mass with Weight

Tags: protein, muscle-mass

I am on an intermediate level when you talk about workouts. I am working out from last two years but on/off as I get time.

I am 72kgs right now and with an atheletic body type but looks skinny too. You can say Ectomorph.

I have now started workout again since two months and planning for a good protein supplement.

What I am concerned about is

- Gain weight upto 80-85 kgs to get rid of that skinny look
- Increase muscle size at the same time without getting extra fat
- Do this in span of 6 months

I am consistent at workout and do it 5 days a week.

Can anyone pls suggest me a good protein supplement that increases my weight as well as my muscle size and boost my workouts

Thanks.

Comment: Whats your length, and do you know your body fat percentage, and could you maybe give some more info on your current diet, most importantly your current macro-nutrients intake? Further, can you tell us what has happened to your body (weight, fat percentage, strength) in the time so far since you started on your 5 day program, and what type of training are you doing? Are you already on a body building bulking schedule or have you been doing power lifting or cardio rich fitness training? Its important to know your current state and dynamics to determine a decent answer to this question.

Comment: I am 6'3 and body fat percentage is around 20-25. I currently take no supplements and natural home food.

Comment: If your BF% is 20%, you have ~58kg of lean mass at 6'3. I doubt that constitutes an intermediate lifter's physique. What are your stats on the big 3 lifts? (are you male or female btw?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, get rid of the idea of putting on 10kg in 6 months without gaining fat. A six-pack-neurosis is not your friend when you're trying to build muscle. No biggie though, fat is easily cut once you've got the muscle base to work it off.

Second, your stats are very atypical for an intermediate lifter (see my comment above). If you don't hit the [intermediate benchmarks](http://www.exrx.net/Testing/WeightLifting/StrengthStandards.html), you'd fare quite well with [Starting Strength](http://forum.bodybuilding.com/showthread.php?t=998224) (or any other beginner's strength routine, but I don't know much about them).

Even if your lifts are strong already you should be able to build upon that with Starting Strength, given the mass gains you will get. You *will* have to eat like a beast, though (about 4000kcal a day), and you *will* get fat along with the muscle gains.
That said, with the muscle base you build you will be able to get rid of the fat quite fast. If you follow the program for 4 months and cut for 2 months, you'd even meet your 6 month deadline.

Regarding supplementation there's one thing you should consider: Supplements won't fix your diet for you. If you don't get your nutrition in order supplements won't help you much. With that said, there are some supplements which can help you achieve your goals:

- Whey: The most readily available protein supplement. If you're not getting enough protein with your food, this is a good supplement. A shake with 40g of whey after workout is adequate. Getting all your protein from shakes *is not*.
- Creatine: may help increase strength (bolsters ATP production) and muscle size (volumizes cells). Take 5g a day for up to four weeks (loading phase), then drop to 2-3g a day. Take whenever you want, no cycling necessary.

That's the two things I'd recommend. If you want to get the maximum out of your workouts you could think about pre- and post-workout formulas, which contain all sorts of fancy chemicals (beta-alanine, caffein etc.). A word on weight gainers: Most of them are glorified Sugar-shakes, and I highly dislike them for that. If you absolutely have to get half of your 4000kcal in liquid form, drink milk instead.

Comment: I agree to what you have said and I dont mind fat. I just want to get big and look huge. The question here is about the supplement that can help me achieve this and support my overall diet which includes both calories and protein.

Comment: 'support' is the key word :) . I expanded my answer with some info on supplements. Might be that I got a bit preachy there..

Comment: Thanks a ton for you clear explanation. But could you tell me the best protein brand which gives optimum results ?

Comment: Hm... I'm from germany, so ESN Designer Whey would be my pick. But that's probably not available where you're at. If you're in the US, look here: http://bodybuilding.com/store/?_requestid=1642648 They also have a feedback system, so you should find a good whey product with good reviews.

Answer (score 0):

This is a difficult one. You're basically both somewhat under-weight and somewhat over-fat. You want to gain about 2kg a month without gaining fat mass. There are very few people who can manage that, no matter what diet they are on. Given your low FFBM (55 .. 58 kg at 1m90 is pretty low) and given the fact that you are only slightly (if at all depending on your age) over-fat, my advice would be to abandon the 'without getting extra fat' for a while. You have given yourself 6 months (26 weeks), and thats a prety short period, but if you want to go for it, I'dd suggest you try and go for a 20 week bulking period followed by 6 weeks of cutting.

With the 20 week for bulking we are going to have to get you to gain more than half a kg a week, its pretty high but if you focus on the largest muscle groups it might be doable. Forget your biceps and your shoulders for a while and focus on chest, triceps, upper back but most importantly your legs. Give your legs their own day and give them hell. No cardio during bulking, just 8..10 rep sets as heavy as you can manage, taking at least two resting days for each muscle group, if possible 3 resting days for your legs.

Now that we've sketched the settings, about your nutritional question. You need to take care of getting sufficient protein. At your weight about 150g a day.
Now for the protein source, its important that you take in all essential amino acids in sufficient amounts, and animal proteine are the easyest way to do thar. Next to this, you need to look at sources rich in leucine, L-isoleucine L-arginine. I could list some of them, but a quick Google will show you what you can choose from. If you don't want to over complicate things, go for the foods with highest levels of these acids that arn't from plants, but try to limite your carnitine intake and try to aim at the 150g mark for your dayly proteine intake.

In the last 6 weeks you are going to be cutting, at that point you will want to add l-carnitine to the mix. You may want to cut down on the leucine, and L-isoleucine levels in your food, but thats just theoretcally, personaly I've not seen any difference during cutting, but some people claim you should limit bulking acids while cutting.

Finally an other controversial one, it does wonders for some and works disasters for others, but after about 6 weeks into your bulking program you may try to add CLA capsules to your diet. Stay on top of your body fat and body mass and see what it does for you. If you see yourself getting fatter faster than in the first 6 weeks, stop, CLA is not for you, you do not want to make your final 6 weeks impossible, but otherwise continue taking the capsules to your diet as they likely help you in your bulking.